# Ski __ Mont Blanc. What is the correct proposition to use and why?

Tags: prepositions

I came across a sentence "go skiing at Mt Everest". I searched on the Internet and tried to find the usage of prepositions after ski, but could not find a satisfying result.

This might be too short a question to ask, but what comes in the blank?

Comment: We would speak of _skiing at [name of a resort]_, but it sounds odd to me with the name of a mountain. I'm no skier, but I would think _on [the slopes of] Mount X_.

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skiing+%2A+Mont&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cskiing%20%2A%20Mont%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bskiing%20at%20Mont%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bskiing%20on%20Mont%3B%2Cc0) showing that both ***in*** and ***at*** are in common use for your context. Obviously they can't have different *meanings*, so just choose whichever you like best.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Actually, it shows **on** and **at**, not **in**!

Comment: @KateBunting: Oops! Well, I did say ***see*** the NGram, so anyone who just took my text at face value has only themselves to blame! The substantive point is that the choice of preposition is *optional*, and it's not hard to find online resources telling you which choices *other people* have been making over decades or even centuries.

Comment: Some (most?) of the 'at' results probably refer to resorts whose name begins with _Mont_, such as Mont-Tremblant in Canada, rather than mountains _per se_.

Answer (score 1):

If you started up high on Mt Blanc and finished somewhere near the bottom, I'd use "Skied down Mt Blanc".

You can also use a direct object: "I've skied Mt Blanc"

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to a ski resort to spend a typical ski holiday, you ski at the resort.

> *We are going skiing **at** Steamboat.*

If perhaps you are a more experienced skier going skiing with a small group where there is no ski resort, you would report the name of the mountain where you will ski.

> *We are going skiing **on** Mount Everest.*

The same phrase can be expressed

> *We are going to ski Mount Everest*.

If you are travelling to particular country or mountainous region of the world you are skiing in that place.

> *We are going skiing **in** Switzerland.
>
> We are going skiing **in** the Rockies.*

As James K mentions, to indicate that you will ski down a particular run or mountain you would say

> *We are going to ski **down** Dead Man's Passage at Brekenridge.*

Once again you can just drop the preposition and say

> *We are going to ski Dead Man's Passage.*

All downhill skiing is assumed to ski **down** something.